# Loading screen during render (asynchronous rendering)

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, rendering

I have one complex component, that is rendering a few seconds. This component contains large canvas with a lot of items. Is there any way how to render some icon during waiting on this `Print` component?

```js
render(){
  const {data} = this.props;
  return(
    <Page>
      <div className="item column-3" id="graphColumn">
        {this.state.loading ? <img src={loadingIcon}/> : false}
        <div className={this.state.loading ? "hidden" : "visible"}>
          <Print channels={this.state.channels} readyToRender={this.readyRender.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Page>
  )
}
readyRender(){
  this.setState({
    loading: false
  })
}
```

I tried to set `display:none` during rendering, and after  in `componentDidMount` in `Print` component set `display:auto`, but this doesn't work.It take long time too. Any tips for solution?

Comment: can you show more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways, but probably not in the sense you were hoping for.

React executes its rendering synchronously which means nothing else can be run in parallel. However, if you can control **when** a time-consuming render will be executed, you can add your waiting icon beforehand.

Here's an example:

```js
var Demo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {loading: true};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({loading: false});
    }, 1000);  //delay this to allow React to actually render the initial state. Can be set to just 10ms, but then font-awesome css doesn't load in time from CDN.
  },
  render: function() {
    if(!this.state.loading) return <div>{this.simulateSlowRender()}</div>;
    return <div><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> loading...</div>;
  },
  simulateSlowRender: function() {
    let arr = new Array(10000000);
    arr.push("done!");  //the last item prints "done".
    return <div>{arr.map((item) => item)}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Warning:** Note that this will "hang" your entire application until rendering is complete. Javascript animations are unlikely to work during that time.

Comment: Its a sad to hear that. And yes, i can control when a time-consuming render will be executed, but it will be nice if i can show during it some gif/animation icon :/

Comment: Well you *can* use css to animate, as shown with the font-awesome icon above. Javascript animations won't work though.

Comment: Will css animation work? Becouse i tried gif, and gif animation was stopped when component was rendering after 10 seconds..

Comment: Yes it will. Run my code above - the spinning icon is animated with css. Gif probably won't work though.

Comment: Ok i am working on it, only one problem i have, - `@fa-font-path:        "../fonts";` path to fonts? I haven't got any fonts file in my project

Comment: You can either download font-awesome, which also has a fonts folder, or add the external stylesheet file as I did (check the `<link>` tag in my code).

Comment: Thank u so much !! This is acceptable solution for me

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck.